# Getting error after upgrading spring boot to 2.3.8 -Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I had upgraded spring boot to 2.3.8 and now while running the application am getting the following error and the service is not starting.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Following are the mongodb related dependencies am using:

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.3.0.RELEASE"
implementation "org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12.8"
```

---

### UPDATE

If am adding the following dependency then the application starts but it fails while doing an insert operation using CRUD repositories:

```
implementation "org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:3.0.0.RELEASE"
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertOne(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/mongodb/client/result/InsertOneResult;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at com.davinta.commons.util.service.filter.GatewayAuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilter(GatewayAuthenticationTokenFilter.java:89)
```

Comment: it is strange that you say you upgrade spring-boot to 2.3.8 but you are still using the 2.3.0 mongodb starter

Comment: @KenChan - I tried removing the version as well, but still no luck!

Comment: Remove the version and don't mess with dependency versions. You are using incompatible library versions hence the error.

Comment: @M.Deinum - If am removing the versions then it is giving MongoDatabaseFactory Class not found error

Comment: If you are removing the version and get that error you are still messing around with incompatible versions somewhere in your list of dependencies.